# How to convert a column of hex to dec in gawk, strtonum in gawk gives erroneous results

Tags: linux, conversion, awk, hexadecimal

I am trying to script a database from a network stream. The network stream after being heavily sed'd drops a three column file that looks something like this called file.db

> 123.123.123.123,computer name,110000103e21cc4
>
> 123.123.123.124,computer2,11000010416200f
>
> 123.123.123.1,computer3,110000106eb3f43

i tried to use this gawk command with no avail

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $1,$2,strtonum("0x"$3)}' file.db
```

the output from the above looks like this

> 123.123.123.123,computer name,76561198025415874
>
> 123.123.123.124,computer2,76561198028824592
>
> 123.123.123.1,computer3,76561198076346171

however the output should convert to this

> 123.123.123.123,computer name,76561198025415876
>
> 123.123.123.124,computer2,76561198028824591
>
> 123.123.123.1,computer3,76561198076346179

the output is always off by a minor amount, so i am assuming some library on the system is not correct... btw this is an embedded system this is running on and i know it can convert cause ive done it with bc, printf, etc etc

How can I make this work

Answer (score 0):

Internally `gawk` stores the converted value to a double precision floating point, so the small discrepancy is just round-off error inheritant to any floating point value. To get accurate result, `gawk` needs to out-source number handling to other commands that support arbitrary precision numbers, such as `bc`.

However, with current `gawk` syntax it is impossible to do complex shell command line parsing within gawk, therefore it would need a shell script helper first. Let's name it `bc.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "ibase=16\n$1" | bc -q
```

This script feeds `ibase=16` and the first argument (hex number) into `bc`, so that `bc` outputs corresponding decimal number. Then `gawk` would be called this way:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} { "./bc.sh " toupper($3) | getline b; print $1,$2,b}' file.db
```

This tells `gawk` to call the shell script with upper-cased $3 (`bc` doesn't support lower case hex value), store result into `b` variable, and print all arguments in one go.

Beware that `./bc.sh` must have some space appended inside double quote, otherwise it will attempt to execute non-existent file such as `./bc.sh110000103E21CC4`.

Comment: this works if i do the previous code and a trimming of column three and then use paste, but i would prefer something that could be done with awk.  This is because if there is anything that breaks the formation of the db file, ie an extra line or more that wasnt parsed out with sed, it causes massive problems with the paste.  remember this is a live stream input from ngrep and while the sed script that isn't posted has been pretty well honed some things can slip through... the output of this section of the script is combined with a larger databse, and integrity is a must

Comment: @Chris Using awk is possible, but given its limitation on number value some kind of external filter has to be used. Though `awk` can call external programs, the hacky way to solve this problem leads me to believe writing a shell script (using `cut` and `bc`) is better suited for this task than `awk` alone. Anyway, I'll modify solution to fit your requirement, it's up to you to decide how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I look back on this and the way that I ended up doing this is

making a bash script like so called convert12345678.sh

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
(echo -e "ibase=16\nobase=0A" ; echo $1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z') | bc | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/\ //g'
```

and then in gawk for whatever i needed say like in the op ( i have heavily modified that program since ) was something like this, and i piped this program but i will demonstrate from a file

```
gawk -F, '{printf("%s,%s,",$1,$2)};{system("/files/convert12345678 "$3)};{printf("\n")}' file.db
```

i did it this way removing the new line in the bash script because honestly i moved it around afterwards, the script execution placement that is, so this way i wouldnt have the newline interjected into the output immediately after the conversion unless i wanted it to with printf